# How to get data types from fields in multiple CSV files?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I can easily loop through all CSV files in a folder like this.

```
import glob
path = 'C:\\path\\*.csv'
for fname in glob.glob(path):
    print(fname)
```

I'm trying to figure out how to open each file and read the file name into a list.  Also, I want to read the first n-rows of each file and read the 'data type' of each into the same list, under the file name.  The files have varying numbers of columns, and they all look something like this:

```
02|1|CD_6MO_SEC_MRKT_MNTH_AVG  |2018-30-31
03|6|CD_6MO_WKLY               |2018-30-31
04|23|CMT_10YR_MNTH             |2018-30-31
05|31|CMT_10YR_WKLY_AVG         |2018-30-31
```

So, in this case, the first column is a String,
the second is an Integer,
the third is a String,
and the forth is a Date.

So, I'd like to write the following to a list:
File1.CSV
String:
Integer:
String:
Date:
Here is another example.

```
6033888|20181001|1.6|20250901|3.362|-999.|20180101|20180101|WSJ 1-YEAR LIBOR
6033891|20181001|1.61|20251001|3.76|-999.|20180101|20180101|WSJ 1-YEAR LIBOR
6034109|20181001|1.773|20181101|3.977|-999.|20180101|20180101|WSJ 1-YEAR LIBOR
```

Here, I'd like to write (to the same list):

File2.CSV

```
String:
String:
Float:
String
Float:
Float:
Date:
Date:
String:
```

These files don't have headers, so I want to check the data type and try to make an educated guess as to what the data type is, based on what the data looks like.  Is it possible to do this?

Comment: How do you determine that `20181001` is a String and `20180101` is a Date in File2?

Comment: Well, that's a great question!  I'm just assuming records that look like dates and have  characters like -, /, or something like a date format, is a date.  I'm assuming without those characters is a string.  You can almost always coerce it into another format, or parse a field into a data format.

Comment: Use `pandas` - `pandas.read_table(...)` is all you need. As a result you will get `pandas DataFrame` (table) where every column will be of appropriate data type - int, float or text. Columns to parse (or to try to parse) into datetime should be indicated individually.

Comment: That's it!  Thanks a lot!!